# Modelling country adjacency in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql, graph

I'm trying to model which countries border each other in MySQL. I have three tables:

```
nodes
-----
node_id MEDIUMINT

countries
---------
country_id MEDIUMINT (used as a foreign key for nodes.node_id)
country CHAR(64)
iso_code CHAR(2)

node_adjacency
--------------
node_id_1 MEDIUMINT (used as a foreign key for nodes.node_id)
node_id_2 MEDIUMINT (used as a foreign key for nodes.node_id)
```

I appreciate the nodes table is redundant in this example, but this is part of a larger architecture where nodes can represent many other items other than countries.

Here's some data (IDs (which appear in all three tables) and countries)

```
59  Bosnia and Herzegovina
86  Croatia
130 Hungary
178 Montenegro
227 Serbia
232 Slovenia
```

Croatia is bordered by all the other countries, and this is represented in the node_adjacency table as:

```
59  86
86  130
86  178
86  227
86  232
```

So Serbia's ID may appear as a `node_id_1` or a `node_id_2`. The data in this table is essentially non directed graph data.

Questions:

Given the name 'Croatia', what SQL should I use to retrieve its neighbours?

```
Bosnia and Herzegovina
Hungary
Montenegro
Serbia
Slovenia
```

Would there be any retrieval efficiency gains in storing the adjacency information as directed graph data? E.g. Croatia borders Hungary, and Hungary borders Croatia, essentially duplicating storage of the relationships:

```
86  130
130 86
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just off the top of my head, so I don't know if it's the most performant solution and it may need a tweak, but I think it should work:

```
SELECT
     BORDER.country
FROM
     Countries AS C
LEFT OUTER JOIN Node_Adjacency NA1 ON
     NA1.node_id_1 = C.country_id OR
     NA1.node_id_2 = C.country_id
INNER JOIN Countries AS BORDER ON
     (
     BORDER.country_id = NA1.node_id_1 OR
     BORDER.country_id = NA1.node_id_2
     ) AND
     BORDER.country_id <> C.country_id
 WHERE
     C.country = 'CROATIA'
```

Since your graph is not directed, I don't think that it makes sense to store it as a directed graph. You might also want to Google "Celko SQL Graph" as he has done a lot of advanced work on trees, graphs, and hierarchies in SQL and has an excellent book devoted to the subject.

Comment: Already got SQL For Smarties and Trees And Hierarchies, but unfortunately a lot of Celko's writing goes way over my head. Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 2):

I would store both relations (Hungary borders Croatia, Croatia borders Hungary) so that you only ever need to query one column.

```
SELECT c.country FROM countries AS c 
INNER JOIN node_adjacency AS n 
ON n.node_id_1 = c.countryID
WHERE c.countryID = 86
```

Answer (score 2):

To do both columns, simply union two queries together (borrowing from Matthew Jones):

```
SELECT c.country FROM countries AS c 
INNER JOIN node_adjacency AS n 
ON n.node_id_1 = c.countryID
WHERE c.countryID = 86
UNION
SELECT c.country FROM countries AS c 
INNER JOIN node_adjacency AS n 
ON n.node_id_2 = c.countryID
WHERE c.countryID = 86
```

If you do it this way, you duplicate your query instead of your data (use 50% less space), and it's still really simple.

Comment: I got this far, but if I only had the word 'Croatia' and not 86, can it still be done?

Comment: Yes; simply change the WHERE clauses.

Answer (score 1):

If you are duplicating relationships (i.e. country A shares border with B, and B shares border with A) you can get a way with a simple select. If you store only one relationship per pair of countries you will need to search by both columns in node_adjacency table (running two select statements and performing a union).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a union view to avoid duplication:

```
CREATE VIEW adjacency_view (node_id_1, node_id_2)
AS
SELECT node_id_1, node_id_2 FROM node_adjacency
UNION ALL
SELECT node_id_2, node_id_1 FROM node_adjacency
```

So your query becomes quite straightforward:

```
SELECT c1.country
FROM adjacency_view
INNER JOIN countries AS c1 on c1.country_id = adjacency_view.node_id_1
INNER JOIN countries AS c2 on c2.country_id = adjacency_view.node_id_2
WHERE c2.country = 'CROATIA'
```